# Hook Window Message loop WM_CLOSE

Tags: c

I wanted to 'protect' a certain window from closing. So I wanted to hook WM_CLOSE, WM_DESTOY or WM_QUIT. And this is what I tried to do so:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        MSG* msg = (MSG*)lParam;
        //if (msg->hwnd == GetForegroundWindow())
        {
            if (msg->message == WM_CLOSE || msg->message == WM_QUIT || msg->message == WM_DESTROY)
            {
                //MessageBox(0, "TEST", "", 0);
                msg->message = 0;
                CallNextHookEx(hMsg, nCode, (WPARAM)NULL, (LPARAM)NULL);
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    CallNextHookEx(hMsg, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I tried:

- Returning TRUE or FALSE
- Calling CallNextHookEx with NULL as LPARAM or
  editing the msg->message to 0

Also what I noticed, if I hook WH_GETMESSAGE it doesn't 'block' the message loop. But it does so with hooking WH_CALLWNDPROC. I discovered this with prompting a messagebox when the msg->message equals to WM_CLOSE.

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Comment: So if Windows is sending your app a message to shut it down you will ignore it?

Comment: @ZippyV Yes on a specific hWnd that I 'protect'. I want to protect a window from clicking the close button. I'm not sure I need to block WM_QUIT and WM_DESTROY as well. But I just tried it.

Comment: `WM_DESTROY` just notifies you that the window is about to be destroyed (`DestroyWindow()` has been called), nothing can be done to prevent it. `WM_QUIT` notifies that the current message loop is to be exited, not usually sent to windows, but to threads (usually with `PostQuitMessage()`). You are right about `WM_CLOSE`, though: it is called when the user clicks the _close_ button (or presses Alt-F4), and the default implementation just calls `DestroyWindow()`.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to "protect" this window?  I can't think of any good reasons why you would ever need to attempt this.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Its not really malicious, its not I going to implent to a RAT or something, its just a personal protection application.

Comment: @IVision: I didn't mean to suggest you were doing something malicious.  My point is that what you're trying to do is very unorthodox.  If you tell us _why_ you want to do this, we might be able to help you find a better way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Well exactly like I told, I just tell you an example, I have a teacher who just click all the windows away. So I thought I 'protect' them, but I think subclassing works fine, I just need to figure out how to exactly, but I'll figure it out I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WH_GETMESSAGE installs a hook for messages that are retrieved from the message queue.  It does allow you to modify the message.  But the problem is that WM_CLOSE is not posted to the message queue with PostMessage(), it is sent with SendMessage().  This hook can't see it.

WH_CALLWNDPROC installs a hook that runs just before the window procedure is called.  Which will allow you to see WM_CLOSE.  However, you are not allowed to modify the message or make it disappear.

There is no hook that allows you to do what you want to do.  Instead you have to *sub-class* the window procedure.  So that your own custom window procedure is called before the window's own procedure.  Now you can simply filter WM_CLOSE by just not calling the old window procedure.

Beware that you still need the same kind of plumbing that SetWindowsHookEx() provides, you still need to inject a DLL with your window procedure into the process.  Best way is to still use SetWindowsHookEx to get that done with a dummy hook that doesn't otherwise do anything.

Comment: How would I subclass? A friend show me how to, but the problem we both have is how to get the original proc address to return to. Because subclassing overwrites all other WM_* so how do I return it to its original procedure?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#subclassing_window

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to install a hook, just subclass the window and have your subclass WndProc ignore the `WM_CLOSE` while forwarding all the other messages.

You can't and shouldn't try to stop `WM_QUIT`.  As rodrigo pointed out, you can't do anything about `WM_DESTROY`.  At that point, `DestroyWindow` has already been called, and your window is going away whether you like it or not.