# How to use WinAPI , prevent/cancel a window closing？

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to prevent users from closing a window by Alt + F4 or by clicking the close button.

How to achieve this?

I guess the windows API can do it, but I don't have any experience, and I can't find a specific solution.

Of course, it's good to be able to implement it,don't have to use a specific API.

---

Background: it is very difficult to find the last place  in Word after closing it for a few days. After word2013, word2013 brought with it a way to return to the previous reading position, but that thing is very unstable and often can't be saved. When word is closed, I want to stop closing and pop up a notice to remind me to add a bookmark before exiting.

Comment: Please describe what language or framework you are using. In general what you need to do is listen to the `WM_CLOSE` message and discard it, but it's hard to say how to do that without knowing your situation. And maybe an even simpler way would be disabling the button, which can be done by disabling the corresponding entry (`SC_CLOSE`) in the system menu.

Comment: Those actions trigger a `WM_CLOSE` message; if you handle this in your WndProc and simply return without taking any action the window won't close.

Comment: @CherryDT   I forgot to say, that the window of that program is not my program.

Comment: If an answer doesn't solve your issue, don't accept that answer. Please take the [tour] to learn, how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Hm, but the popup says "Accept this answer if it solved your problem **or was the most helpful in finding your solution**". I agree that the OP probably should have waited for better answers than mine, especially since I turned out to be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** *This won't work, as it turned out. At least the message hook won't work because the message is posted and not sent, and about the CBT hook I'm not sure either, and I can't test it at the moment to give an evidence-based statement. The solution is probably to subclass the window but this is also non-trivial and I can't explain it properly and with working examples right now. I can't delete this answer though because it already has a comment. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915332/hook-window-message-loop-wm-close) for more info. So take it with a grain of salt. I'm turning the answer to community wiki, feel free to edit it and fix/improve the solution!*

**EDIT2:** *Seems even subclassing won't be enough because Word is doing things its own way.*

---

You need a [windows hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks). Either a CBT hook or a getmessage hook will do.

You have to create a DLL for this to work. The hook handler must be located in the DLL. It must have the same bitness as Word (probably 64 Bit). Then you call `SetWindowsHookEx` to install a global hook.

In the hook, you will have to check whether the current action is a window-closing attempt (in a CBT hook you would check for a `HCBT_SYSCOMMAND` of `SC_CLOSE`, in a getmessage hook you would check for a `WM_CLOSE` message), and whether it is about a Word window (for example using the window class - not sure if it has a recognizable class, you'd have to check - or the process' executable file name which you can get using `GetModuleFileName` since you will run inside Word's process) and prevent the action (by returning 1 from a CBT hook or returning 0 from a getmessage hook - to *allow*, call `CallNextHookEx`).

Comment: Actually it turns out this won't work after all because the close message is sent and not posted. You may have to subclass the window, which is more complicated...

Comment: Indeed, it's much, *much* more complicated than even that. Word 2013 doesn't use a standard `HWND`. Which means that you cannot even use the standard approach of subclassing a window. You're going to have to reverse-engineer how Word 2013 handles user interaction, and take it from there.

Comment: I don't really know but maybe [writing an add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/) could bring you closer...?

Comment: It seems that I should "develop plug-ins", thank you @CherryDT